# How can I annotate this tail recursive Scala function

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I have a function that i know is tail recursive. But because of the way I define it, the compiler complains about the function having a recursive call in non tail position. This is the function.

```scala
@tailrec
def travel: (Int, List[Char]) => Int = {
    case (n,        Nil) => n
    case (n, '~' :: sls) => travel(0, sls)
    case (n, '^' :: sls) => travel(max(n-1,0), sls)
    case (n, '>' :: sls) => travel(n+1, sls)
    case (_,  s  :: sls) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal selector '" + s + "'")
}
```

I get

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method travel: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
def travel: (Int, List[Char]) => Int = {
```

If I write it as this, it works fine.

```scala
@tailrec
def travel(n:Int, l:List[Char]): Int = (n,l) match {
    case (n,        Nil) => n
    case (n, '~' :: sls) => travel(0, sls)
    case (n, '^' :: sls) => travel(max(n-1,0), sls)
    case (n, '>' :: sls) => travel(n+1, sls)
    case (_,  s  :: sls) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal selector '" + s + "'")
}
```

I think it has something to do with the `def: (Input) => Output = {}` type declaration style. I use it because it looks cleaner than writing nested matches, or a match on a tuple.

Comment: I think the whole question could be reformatted as: *"Can we add a `@tailrec` annotation to an anonymous function ?"*

Comment: @paradigmatic - That's a different question, but a good one.  Not an annotation, but a way for an anonymous function to make the tail recursive call.  (It can't see its own `apply` method.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two are not the same.  In the first case, the method *produces a function* that then calls the method again (that produces a function, etc.).  That is, you're creating a new instance of `Function1[(Int, List[Char]), Int]` each time you call `travel` in the first case.  Unsurprisingly, this cannot be converted into a jump instruction.  (In theory one could, but the analysis would be quite complicated, as one would have to un-do all those object creations.)

In the second case, it's just a method calling itself, which can be converted into a jump.